# Why does cache use Most Recently Used (MRU) algorithm as evict policy?

Tags: java, algorithm, caching

I know the algorithms of MRU and its reversed one Least Recently Used (LRU).

I think LRU is reasonable, as LRU element means it will be used at least possible in future. However, MRU element means the element is very possible to be used in future, why evict it? What is the reasonable scenario?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Imagine you were looking up the details of buses as they arrived at a bus stop, based on their bus number (or whatever identifier you use).

It's somewhat reasonable to think that if you've *just* seen a number 36 bus, you're *less* likely to see another one imminently than to see one of the other buses that stops there.

Just one example, but the idea is more general: in some cases, having "just seen something" is a good indicator that you're *unlikely* to see the same thing again soon.

Comment: Riding on a bus at the moment :)?

Comment: @Petar: As it happens, I am now, but I was on a train when I wrote this post :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Doesn't this goes against the temporal locality principle?

Comment: @shingaridavesh: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @JonSkeet The analogy given by you says that if we have seen one bus then it is unlikely to see the bus again in recent time. But temporal locality says that if a block is accessed then it will be accessed soon in time. Am I missing something?

Comment: @shingaridavesh: Yes - you're missing the fact that not every situation is the same. Sometimes you're more likely to use the same value again soon, and sometimes you're less likely to. That's why there are both MRU and LRU algorithms - so you can choose whichever is most appropriate for your situation.

Comment: @JohnSkeet - If we evict the most recently used one, then it seems that we also need an LRU cache to reduce cache miss rate. Something like, as we remove most-recently-used element from an MRU cache, we would also add this to an LRU cache. Further if this addition evicts any element, then we need to add that LRU-evicted element to the MRU cache. Not sure how an empty MRU cache would be populated otherwise!!

Comment: @KGhatak: Not quite sure what you mean, but you certainly don't *always* need to caches...

Comment: @JohnSkeet - Typically, we would always have a policy/algorithm on how an empty cache would be filled up gradually (let's ignore the auto fill option right now). The algorithm for LRU cache is very intuitive - for each cache miss, we get the data from an authoritative source say DB and populate the cache. For MRU cache, I wonder what would be corresponding algorithm - would you pls throw some light!

Comment: @KGhatak: Well I'd really only considered the simplest form of cache: populate on demand, up to some limit, at which point appropriate entries are removed to make space for new ones. I don't think I've got any particularly good info here...

Comment: @JohnSkeet - Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps a more tangible example would be a media server. When the user has completed watching a video (let's say it's an episode of a TV show), they are presumably the least likely to want to view it again. So if you must evict something, evict the most recently viewed item.

In practice though, I believe this type of cache is typically used in addition to an LRU or LFU cache, where the two caches in tandem allow you to cover a wide variety of cases.

Answer (score 5):

I think the both @Jon Skeet and @Jeremiah Willcock's answers are describing using MRU as a way to avoid polluting the cache with useless entries.

1. This only works if your cache APIs allow you to change the policy on the fly; e.g. on a per-request basis.  Setting your cache policy to MRU in "normal" situations is probably a bad idea ... because your cache becomes ineffective once it fills up.
2. MRU has the problem that if you get a hit on an entry that is often used in "normal" mode while doing MRU lookups, you end up throwing out the entry ...

Better alternatives to MRU for doing a scan without poluting the cache are:

- bypass the cache entirely,
- probe the cache without doing a read through / update, and without altering the LRU chains.

---

For what it is worth, I cannot think of any use-cases for MRU that don't fit this general pattern.

---

Incidentally, @Jon Skeet's example of buses arrivals is not always borne out in reality due the bunching effect.

- If a bus is running late, there are likely to be more than average people waiting at each bus stop.  The bus has to stop more frequently, and stays longer at each stop. This slows down the late bus.
- A bus that is on time that is following the late bus will typically have fewer people than the average waiting at each bus stop.  (Because they just go onto the late bus.)  This speeds up the following bus.
- The net result is that the buses tend to bunch up.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_bunching

Answer (score 4):

The use case is when you are iterating through the same (larger-than-cache) data multiple times, and so you will not go back to recently accessed data.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Most_Recently_Used)

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you are caching the seats of a hall for a concert, to expedite the booking. As your application books the seats, remove the cached item from the cache as they are no more required for the booking application.

Answer (score 2):

I know one scenario MRU is better than LRU. In database cache, assume we have a cache that can contain 50 blocks, and we have 2 tables that exceed the size of cache(let's say 51 blocks). For block nested loop join operation, we need to join rows to the other entire table. But since cache is smaller than the entire table, we need to drop some blocks.

For cache policy LRU, it will drop the first block of the table, and replace it with last block of the table. However, when we continue to join next row with the entire table, we find the first block is missing, then we load the first block into the place of last round second block. And cascading reload all the entire table.

But for MRU, we only need to replace the latest block of the table, so that we can reuse all the blocks loaded before.

Hope this can help you